# Difference between transform & target_transform in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

Difference between transform & target_transform in pytorch?

Context:  
 Every TorchVision Dataset includes two arguments: transform and target_transform to modify the samples and labels respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code, particularly the `__getitem__` method for any of the [torchvision Dataset classes](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/datasets.html), e.g., [torchvision.datasets.DatasetFolder](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/_modules/torchvision/datasets/folder.html#DatasetFolder:%7E:text=def%20__getitem__(self,return%20sample%2C%20target), you can see that transform and target_transform are used to modify / augment / transform the image and the target respectively.

Examples where this might be useful include object detection and semantic segmentation, where if you apply a translation / rotation / shear / scale / crop on the source image, you would also want corresponding transforms on the bounding boxes / segmentation masks.

As an additional example, you can take a look at this [official tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/transforms_tutorial.html#transforms) where `target_transform` is used to convert integer class labels to one-hot format for image classification.

Answer (score 1):

`transform` are used to transform and augment input data and features while `target_transform` is used to manipulate the labels associated with those labels such as one hot encoding etc.